# How can I implement a twilio "participant" in an SMS conversation between two people?

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I'm using python-twilio with django. I'd like for my app to be able to participate in SMS dialogs between two (or more) people simply by being included in the conversation. e.g.:

1. Person A texts a question to Person B and twilio# T
2. Person B responds to Person A
3. twilio# T sees B's response and offers more info to Person A

I don't seem to be getting any info in the POST about other numbers in the conversation. Is this a limitation of twilio or of SMS? Or is there a way to get at it that I'm not seeing?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For an example group SMS application you can check out [this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/07/building-a-group-messaging-app-with-meteor-mongodb-and-twilio.html), though it uses Meteor.

Essentially I believe it would have to work as follows because [sending sms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) is inherently one to one:

1. Person A texts question to Twilio# T which forwards to Person B.
2. Person B responds to Twilio# T which forwards to A.
3. Based upon your app logic regarding B's last response, Twilio# T sends a message to Person A.

Please let me know if this helps at all. The [FAQ here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio) might also provide a little more clarity for this scenario.